# Calling c++ web toolkit widget from other webpages?

Tags: c++, web, wt

I am new to the Wt framework, I just wanted to know if its possible to call Wt custom widgets from other web pages. I mean if I make a Wt application can someone use it as an api for their development using any other framework other that Wt or my application will become Wt specific application?

Answer (score 1):

Wt has a 'widgetset' mode, in which you can display widgets of your Wt application on other websites, similar to how you can add google maps widgets to static websites.

Answer (score 0):

As user52875's mentions, you need to tell Wt that your app is a [Wt::widgetSet](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/namespaceWt.html#af4b6ed5fd28b4f5fa141b153c1107349a932eaa79ae0d1f31e3cb240cf5ff0826).

Here's an example, modified from Wt's [helloworld](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/hello) and [homepage](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/wt-homepage) examples:

```
#include <Wt/WServer>
#include <Wt/WText>

using namespace Wt;

class MyApp : public WApplication {
public:
    MyApp(const WEnvironment& env) : WApplication(env) {
        new WText("Hello", root());
    }
};

WApplication *createApplication(const WEnvironment& env)
{
  return new MyApp(env);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  try {
    WServer server(argc, argv, WTHTTP_CONFIGURATION);

    // ********** Pass 'Wt::WidgetSet' instead of 'Wt::Application' here ************
    server.addEntryPoint(WidgetSet, createApplication, "/");

    server.run();

  } catch (Wt::WServer::Exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```